# Problems continuing a MVC project with Entity Famework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, umbraco6

So I have to work on this project (ASP.NET MVC 4 with Umbraco) that uses Entity Framework and I think UmbracoMembeShipProvider.
Now I have to add Roles to the project. In the DB there's a Users table and some few others. There is no Identity/Roles or the sort in the DB. I tried to create a Roles table and a junction table between Users and Roles but then I couldn't update the models. I made an .edmx schema file and it didn't pick up the junction table, just the Roles table with all the columns pilled up from the junction table.

I tried to approach it by making a Roles entity in the .edmx file and then update the DB via migrations, that also didn't work because the project is stuctued in a way that is has a 'Core' project where all the models are and then a 'Web' project where some other models are. And it gave all heaps of errors.

In the Web project there's a 'Migrations' directory with 2 classes one of which has 2 empty methods (up/down) and one that creates some indexes and then a bunch of commented code.

I'm also quite a newbie in ORMs in general so I don't know how to approach this problem, continuing where the other devs, before me, left off.

In the meantime I'll pick up some tutorials about EF but any help or guidance will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the necessary settings in your web.config file which references a connection string pointing to a database where the user/role tables exist. It should look something like this.

```
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider"
         type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="false" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         defaultMemberTypeAlias="Another Type" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" 
         type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="false" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<appSettings>
<add key="umbracoDbDSN" value="server=localhost;database=MSSM;user id=db_user;password=password" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The App-DB connection works as it should. I can create new users, log in, etc. But in the DB I didn't see a connection between the Users table and something that resembles a Role table. So I think the project has UmbracoRoleProvider but it doesn't use it anywere.